# Late static binding & isset in PHP prior 7.0

Tags: php, static, php-5.6, notice

The following code works as expected on PHP 7.0 and newer:

```
class foo {
    const BLAH = [];

    public function bar() {
        return isset(static::BLAH['baz']);
    }
}

var_dump((new foo)->bar());
```

While PHP 5.6 just gives:

`Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)`

Changing the code as suggested leads to a notice (which is expected):

`Notice: Undefined index: baz`

This would work:

```
class foo {
    const BLAH = [];

    public function bar() {
        return null !== static::BLAH['baz'];
    }
}

var_dump(@(new foo)->bar());
```

Is there an alternative that doesn't end in a notice, without prefixing the call with an `@`?

Comment: `return array_key_exists('baz', static::BLAH);`? (Not posting this as an answer yet since I'm not sure you're asking in your case specifically or in a more general sense.)

Comment: Well, seeing this answer makes me feel embrassed. Works perfectly. Thank you :)

Comment: Happy to help! Let me post this as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`array_key_exists`](http://www.php.net/array_key_exists) instead, which should work without any issue with PHP5.

```
return array_key_exists('baz', static::BLAH);
```

Note that a minor difference with `isset` is that `array_key_exists` will always return `true` if `static::BLAH['baz']` is defined, whereas `isset` will return `false` if it's defined but its value is `null`.